# Subscriber issue

Tags: ros, range, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What should I do if I want that the callBack function of a subscriber returns a value. In particular I have a subscriber that receive sensor_msgs/Range and I want the callBack function to return the range value that is in the message but I don't now how to implement it.
Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58522/subscriber-issue/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2013-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Callback cannot return values.

Where would you want to have that value returned to?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aimc](https://answers.ros.org/users/3966/aimc/) on 2013-03-19**:
You could take an example from the talker tutorial, to communicate to the sender of the original message.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-19**:
That's what services are for.

**Comment by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on 2013-03-19**:
I want it returned in the main where I declare the subscriber

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-19**:
You just want to have the message value available in the main? You could write it to a global variable or better use boost::bind for the callback and pass in a reference to the value to write to.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you just want to get the value, declare the callback as member function of a class. Then, you can write the received data into that class, in example (pseudocode):

```
void Robot::LaserCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& msg){

for ( range_data in msg) {
    this->rangedata = msg->ranges
    }
}
```

In this way from your main you could just call a get method to obtain the latest data available.

---

Originally posted by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) with karma: 483 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1